# Glassfish local and external server encodes characters differently

Tags: java, glassfish

I am importing some .csv files, which gets inserted into my database. When I run the Glassfish server on my local server through NetBeans, the data is being inserted without errors and it shows the correct characters (`æøå` being the main characters).

However, when I upload the files to my Glassfish server and redeploy it (using my .war file), the characters look all weird when I upload the .csv file and it inserts the data into the database.

When I upload my file locally and execute it locally (but gets insert into the server), it will look like this:

```
Idrætsforening
```

But when I upload and redeploy my project, it looks like this:

```
Idr��tsforening
```

When I do `System.out.println()` with the data locally, the data is shown correctly. When I do it on my server, the `æøå` characters are shown as `?`. So it will say `Idr?tsforening`

I am not sure what code I can show you, but I did add `?characterEncoding=utf8` to my JDBC connection and I did add a property to my Connection Pool on my Glassfish server: `characterEncoding = UTF-8`.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Is the database the same instance in both cases ?

Comment: @Berger Yes that is correct. The code is exactly the same locally and on the server.